# Stuck in level 29 in samurai vs zombies defense 2

Tags: samurai-vs-zombies-2

I have been stuck at level 29, and I know I should be farming farmers, but I can't win. I have 1000 points, and I have already spent all of my coins, upgrading kunoichi to the maximum level.

How can I beat level 29?